# Is there a tool to export C# to HTML with syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, export

I am looking for some way to export a .cs file to an .html file for posting on the web but my searches aren't helping much.  I remember years ago an IDE called DevC++ could do this for C code, but I'm not sure how I'd do it with C# 4.

Can Visual Studio do this somehow?

Comment: microsoft do is own plugin for VS 2017, just add "copy as html plugin" in plugin center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Addins.

- 2008: http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/
- 2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/656f8df1-13ae-47b3-8f9a-89bf107c3b2a

Answer (score 4):

Copy and paste to word.
Save as HTML.

It's not pretty markup, but it works.

Comment: The body of the markup isn't actually *that* bad. A span around each color change, which is expected no matter what; one or two custom MSO style attributes and redundant font family.

Comment: Anything more than the basics in word is just sooo hard to 'read' especially if you want to modify it

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting it using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). The Plugin you want to use is NppExport. Last I checked, HTML and RTF are supported.

Comment: +1 for the Neat tip.  But I think I'm doing something wrong -- as it doesn't seem to work... when I go to paste it somewhere else, it's like the clipboard is empty. I tried selecting the whole file before pressing "Copy HTML to Clipboard" but still no dice.

Comment: Reply to my above post: While I wasn't able to make the "Copy HTML to Clipboard" action work, the "Export as HTML" ended up working fine. :-)