# Command-line tool to syntax highlight C# into HTML?

Tags: c#, command-line, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for an easy way to syntax highlight C# code into HTML from the command line. Ideally this would be something like:

```
syntax-highlighter test.cs
```

... produces test.html.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925901/is-there-a-tool-to-export-c-to-html-with-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Actually this is not an exact duplicate, because you are asking for command-line tools. But that question may prove useful anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this is part of an automated benchmarking tool, which needs the source code besides the metrics. It would be great if it was highlighted, as there is a lot of source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter). It doesn't literally translate C# to HTML source, but instead uses javascript. All you have to do it link to the JS files. For example:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <pre class="brush: csharp;">
    //put all your code here
    public class Hello1
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
       }
    }
    </pre>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css"></link>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shThemeDefault.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is very good.

It would be really easy to write a script which uses the template above and simply cats out your source code in the right place.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed! I was piping everything into an HTML file I was building, and this requires just adding one more piece to the HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A very good one is [pygments](http://pygments.org).

The command is

```
pygmentize -f html /path/to/test.cs
```

Supports lots of languages, including C#. Requires python.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GeSHi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/). It is an syntax highlighter for PHP, so you can write a very simple command-line PHP script that will take a name as argument and spit out the highlighted version.